# Create a monthly mean column in multiple years

Tags: python, pandas, average, mean

I have a 'dates' column and a 'tmax' column. I want to create one another column that shows each month's average in each year. I tried

```
    df['date']=pd.date_range(start='1/01/1980', end='31/12/2015')
    #df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y') format of date
    df['means'] = df.resample('M', on='date').mean()
```

I have got

```
    ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```

Sample values are below:

```
    date        tmax
    1-Jan-80    15.773
    2-Jan-80    18.342
    ...
    30-Jan-80   15.851
    31-Jan-80   11.962
    ...
    1-Dec-80    15.773
    2-Dec-80    18.342
    ...
    30-Dec-80   15.851
    31-Dec-80   11.962
    1-Jan-81    15.773
    2-Jan-81    18.342
    ...
    30-Jan-81   15.851
    31-Jan-81   11.962
    ...
    1-Dec-2015  15.773
    2-Dec-2015  18.342
    ...
    30-Dec-2015 15.851
    31-Dec-2015 11.962
```

Comment: can you check the data type of the date column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate dataframe for `mean` and merge it the original, followed by backfill of NaN values.

```
import numpy as np

# calculate & store `mean` in a new dataframe
df2 = df.set_index('date')['tmax'].resample('M', how=[np.mean]).reset_index(drop=False)

# merge 2 dataframes
pd.merge(df, df2, on='date', how='left').fillna(method='bfill')
```